# Git http push failed

Tags: git, push

I am trying to make this work, but it does not work.

I usually do not have problems when I push to the server but now I keep getting this:

```
git push origin master
Password for 'https://JZ0258213@111.23.15.321':
Fetching remote heads...
refs/
refs/tags/
refs/heads/
updating 'refs/heads/master'
from 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
to   1c51a98a88f51fa3fe9ab527a6413f117fade432
sending 1468 objects
PUT 55113af6418f7w77c9a87b3b470c53a64e62e314 failed, aborting (22/403)
Updating remote server info
UNLOCK HTTP error 400
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

When I try to do clone a file from the server or when I try to use any other command,it works fine, it is just the 'push' command which is not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I just needed to use 'git gc' and when I pushed again it worked.

Comment: I have the similar problem but git gc does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The httpd user needs write access to all repo files.
The best option would be to chown -R all files to the httpd user.